# Windows services does not run my class method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows service application which would scan the wifi list and save to file. then i will read the file and write to mysql database and close the file. my wifi scanning and db methods in another class within same windows service project which i invoke in service class. I am able to run and install the windows service but i think those methods are not called. I have even tried them in the service class but they still didn't call up in OnStart method. When i run it section mode and debug from visual studio it works fine but when i install it in installutil it only starts the service nothing happens though the service still runs in the background. I've created windows form version of this and that works fine.

Comment: then you need to add logging to find out what it is doing, and what its not.   if you create windows, or try accessing network mapped drives or all sorts, can stop it from working

Comment: I am working on the local system not part of a network and defined my service to run on localsystem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more likely that the class method is called but writing the output file fails. The account that is used to run the service likely has no rights to create and/or write the output file. Check the folder that it should be written to and see if the account that runs your service has proper access rights. You can also use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to verify this (set a filter on Path or Process Name).

Comment: Worth noting the typical built-in Windows accounts that run services - LocalSystem will talk to the file system but not on the network; NetworkService will talk on the network but has very few permissions on the local machine including file system.